# An unpleasant measure theory/functional analysis problem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently taking a functional analysis course, and at the moment every student on the course is stumped by a specific question. We're looking at the bounded linear map 
$$
\varphi_n:L^1\left([0,1]\right)\to \mathbb{R},\quad \varphi_n(f) = \int^1_0 f(x)(n\sin(n^2 x)) dx,\quad\|\varphi_n\|=n.
$$

We are attempting to prove the existence of an $f\in L^1$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\varphi_n(f)|\rightarrow \infty$, and from an earlier assignment we know that this function cannot be continuously differentiable. However, nobody has been able to make even the slightest progress. I, and all of us would appreciate a hint or a sketch of proof!

Comment: Can you be more specific with the notation?  Do you mean that $\varphi_n$ is a linear map from, what, $L_1[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?  Do you mean that $[\varphi_n(f)]=|\int_0^1f(x)n\sin(n^2x)dx|$?

Comment: Have you tried for $L^2$ functions such that their Fourier series is a sum of sines? (Provided you take the integral over the full period of the sine and not $[0,1]$)

Comment: Ben: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Let me fix the notation

Comment: What do you mean with norm n?

Comment: For a given n, the operator norm of $\varphi_n$ is n.

Comment: Have you tried uniform boundedness principle?

Comment: Elswyyr: are you computing integrals of $\sin(n^2x)$ over $[0,1]$ ? Meaning, there is no $2\pi$ anywhere?

Comment: Do you know (from context) if it could be possible that no such $f$ exists?

Comment: The assignment is, specifically, to prove the existence of such an $f$, so that would surprise me greatly.

Comment: "unpleasant", lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that for $\alpha\in (\tfrac12,1)$ the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 x^{-\alpha} &\text{if}\;x\in(0,1)
 \\
 0 &\text{if}\;x\not\in (0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies
$$
\varphi_n(f)\to\infty
\qquad(n\to\infty).
$$
The proof requires some estimations because it is probably rather difficult to calculate the integral exactly.

Let $n\geq 3$ be fixed.
For $k\geq 0$, we define
$$
 I_k := \int_{k\pi n^{-2}}^{(k+1)\pi n^{-2}} f(x)(n\sin(n^2 x)) \mathrm dx.
$$
It is clear that $\varphi_n(f) = \sum_{k\geq 0} I_k$ and that $I_k=0$ for large $k$.
It is also easy to see that $I_k\geq0$ if $k$ is even and $I_k\leq0$ if $k$ is odd.

Due to the monotonicity of $f$ it can be shown that
$
I_k+I_{k+1}\geq 0
$
if $k$ is even.

Let us calculate a lower estimate for $I_0+I_1$.
Again, for $k=0,1,2,3$ we define the integrals
$$
 J_k := \int_{k\pi n^{-2}/2}^{(k+1)\pi n^{-2}/2} f(x)(n |\sin(n^2 x)|) \mathrm dx.
$$
It is clear that $I_0=J_0+J_1$ and $I_1=-J_2-J_3$.
For $k=0,1,2,3$ we know that $f(x)\geq ((k+1)\pi n^{-2}/2)^{-\alpha}$.
Therefore we have the lower estimate
$$
 J_k \geq \int_0^{\pi n^{-2}/2}((k+1)\pi n^{-2}/2)^{-\alpha} n \sin(n^2 x)\mathrm dx
 = \dots = ((k+1)\pi/2)^{-\alpha} n^{2\alpha-1}.
$$
On the other hand, for $k=1,2,3$ we know that $f(x)\leq (k\pi n^{-2}/2)^{-\alpha}$
Therefore we have the upper estimate
$$
 J_k \leq \int_0^{\pi n^{-2}/2}(k\pi n^{-2}/2)^{-\alpha} n \sin(n^2 x)\mathrm dx
 = \dots = (k\pi/2)^{-\alpha} n^{2\alpha-1}.
$$
Using these estimates it can be seen that
$$
I_0-I_1
=
J_0+J_1-J_2-J_3
\geq n^{2\alpha-1} ( (\pi/2)^{-\alpha} +(2\pi/2)^{-\alpha}-(2\pi/2)^{-\alpha}-(3\pi/2)^{-\alpha})
= C n^{2\alpha-1}
$$
for some constant $C>0$.

To summarize, we have
$$
\varphi_n(f) \geq I_0+I_1 \geq C n^{2\alpha-1} \to \infty
\quad (n\to\infty).
$$

Comment: Nice examples,+1. I was surprised such elementary examples worked. I gave another proof, which seemed to me simpler.

Answer (score 5):

@supinf showed us a nice set of examples. I think the proof can be simplified. So suppose $1/2<p<1$ and let $f(x)=x^{-p}.$ Let $x=y/n^2$ to see

$$\tag 1 n\int^1_0 x^{-p}\sin(n^2 x)\, dx = n^{2p-1}\int_0^{n^2} y^{-p}\sin(y)\, dy.$$

If we show $\int_0^{\infty} y^{-p}\sin(y)\, dy >0,$ then it will follow that $(1)\to \infty$ on the order of $n^{2p-1}.$ But this integral equals

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\sin y\left(\frac{1}{(2\pi k+y)^p} - \frac{1}{(2\pi k+\pi +y)^p}\right)\,dy.$$

Each of the integrands here is positive on $(0,\pi),$ hence so is the sum, and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform boundedness principle will show that a function $f$ must exist such that $|\phi_n(f)|$ is unbounded. Else $\phi_n(f)$ is bounded for each $f$ in a Banach space, and so $\|\phi_n\|$ would be a bounded sequence of functionals, which it is not. I do not know however how an explicit example would look.

Comment: $|\phi_n(f)|$ unbounded is not the same thins as $|\phi_n(f)| \to \infty$, right?

Comment: As near as I can tell, this proves that there's some f so that $|\varphi_n(f)|$ is unbounded, but, as Kavi commented, not that $|\varphi_n(f)|\rightarrow \infty$. I don't think it's quite sufficient without more arguments.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted. You guys are of course correct.